# Grep strings in a subgroup of lines in txt file

Tags: command-line, grep, awk, text-processing

I have a file that looks like this

```
AAA_21               PF13304.1  x_00004
AAA_22               PF13401.1  x_00004
SMC_N                PF02463.14 x_00004
AAA_29               PF13555.1  x_00004
DUF258               PF03193.11 x_00005
AAA_15               PF13175.1  x_00005
AAA_21               PF13304.1  x_00005
AAA_22               PF13401.1  x_00005
SMC_N                PF02463.14 x_00005
AAA_15               PF13175.1  x_00006
AAA_21               PF13304.1  x_00006
AAA_22               PF13401.1  x_00007
SMC_N                PF02463.14 x_00007
```

Now, for each block of lines that have the same string in column 3 (e.g. x_00004), I want to `grep` only the lines containing specific strings if they are present together in the block.

So, I know that I can use
`grep -f <file containing string> <file to scan>`
But I cannot find a way for applying the first action. I guess `awk` will help me here, but I do not really know how.

I would like to have something like:

```
AAA_21               PF13304.1  x_00004
AAA_22               PF13401.1  x_00004
AAA_21               PF13304.1  x_00005
AAA_22               PF13401.1  x_00005
```

So basically greping the lines containing `PF13304.1` or `PF13401.1` only if they are sharing field 3.

I use `PF13304.1` and `PF13401.1` as example, because sometimes I look for the presence of 3 strings in the block.
One problem is that the string I am looking for are not always consecutive in the file I want to scan.

All the strings I want to `grep` are reported in a txt file as well. I can organize them as I want to match the `grep` command.

Instead the line containing

```
AAA_21               PF13304.1  x_00006
AAA_22               PF13401.1  x_00007
```

Should not be included because the strings I want to `grep` do not share field 3, meaning they are not both present in the subgroups `x_00006` or `x_00007`

So, from the logical point of view I want to

1. open the file
2. divide the lines in groups according with field 3, create group that have the same string in field 3
3. in this subgroups `grep` the strings I am looking for only if they are all present in each block

Comment: so you don't want this lines `AAA_22               PF13401.1  x_00006` and `AAA_22               PF13304.1  x_00005`, if they were exist in your file, right?

Comment: yes I want to have them as well. basically, looking in subset of lines, defined by column 3. In this subset I want to `grep` the string I am interest in.

Comment: Now I really don't understand your question. Sorry and I think this doesn't what you want `grep  '.*PF13\(304\|401\)\.1.*' file`  in fact, ehm?

Comment: Can you show an instance where `PF13304.1` will not appear in the output?

Comment: I updated my question. SO maybe now it is more clear

Comment: But as I [commented in previously](http://askubuntu.com/questions/586085/grep-strings-in-a-subgroup-of-lines-in-txt-file#comment812225_586085) and [your reply](http://askubuntu.com/questions/586085/grep-strings-in-a-subgroup-of-lines-in-txt-file#comment812240_586085) you wants them as well while in body of question you said I don't want that lines? and now it's more unclear at least for me.

Comment: So what you're saying is, *all the strings* in the file should be present in each group?

Comment: @KasiyA I am sorry my mistake. I read both as `x_00006`

Comment: @muru yes you are rigth.

Comment: and one more question: Does `PF13304.1` and `PF13401.1` are always consecutive towards each other? and does always `PF13304.1` appears first of `PF13401.1`? and what if line with `PF13304.1` exist but line `PF1341.1` doesn't exist?

Comment: @KasiyA Good point, they are not consecutive always. If in the same subgroup line with `PF13304.1` exist and the others not, I do not want to take them. However sometimes I have to look for not only 2 strings (e.g. PF13304.1, PF1341.1) but for 3.

Comment: and I flagged it as "unclear what you're asking". Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/586085/edit) the question and make it even more clear (your example of input isn't good to explain your question better). thanks

Comment: @KasiyA Ok, thank. I tried to make it more clear now.

Comment: Can you explain the differences between group, subgroup and block, used in the logical section?

Comment: When you write "Instead the line containing `AAA_21               PF13304.1  x_00006 AAA_22               PF13401.1  x_00007`: That looks like two lines - in which way is that one line? Are you encoding new lines in some special way?

Answer (score 1):

Can be done in Python fairly easily:

```
$ cat input.txt | ./find_strings.py PF13304.1 PF13401.1                                                                  
AAA_21               PF13304.1  x_00004
AAA_22               PF13401.1  x_00004
AAA_21               PF13304.1  x_00005
AAA_22               PF13401.1  x_00005
AAA_21               PF13304.1  x_00006
AAA_22               PF13401.1  x_00007
```

Contents of `find_strings.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
strings=sys.argv[1:]
for line in sys.stdin:
    for string in strings:
         if string in line:
             print line.strip()
```

The way this words is that we redirect contents of input file to script's stdin stream, read the stream line by line, and for each line we make a lookup in the list of arguments that we provide on command-line. Fairly simple approach

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not as simple as `grep`. This program:

- scans the text file, accumulating "blocks" where the 3rd field are the same string
- when it has found a block, invoke `grep` and collect the output
- if the number of lines in the output is the same as the number of search terms, output grep's output

```
awk '
  function grep(block,    m, grep_out, cmd, line, i) {
    m = 0
    delete grep_out

    cmd = "grep -f " ARGV[1]    # define the grep command
    print block |& cmd          # invoke grep, and send the block of text as stdin
    close(cmd, "to")            # close greps stdin so we can start reading the output

    # read from grep until no more output
    while ((cmd |& getline line) > 0)
      grep_out[m++] = line
    close(cmd)

    # did grep find all search terms?  If yes, print the output 
    if (length(grep_out) == nterms)
      for (i=0; i<m; i++) 
        print grep_out[i]
  }

  # read the search terms file, just to count the number of lines
  NR == FNR {
    nterms++
    next
  }

  # if we detect a new block, call grep and start a new block
  section != $3 {
    if (block) grep(block)
    block = ""
    section = $3
  } 

  {block = block $0 RS}   # accumulate the lines in this block

  END {if (block) grep(block)}       # also call grep at end of file

' fileContainingStrings fileToScan
```

produces this output:

```
AAA_21               PF13304.1  x_00004
AAA_22               PF13401.1  x_00004
AAA_21               PF13304.1  x_00005
AAA_22               PF13401.1  x_00005
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you correctly, you want to find all subgroups that contain ALL patterns you specify. This can be done with `sort` and `awk`, e.g.:

```bash
# make sure subgroups are adjacent 
sort -k3,3 infile |

# add a newline between subroups, this allows the next 
# invocation of awk to read each subgroup as a record
awk 'NR > 1 && p!=$3 { printf "\n" } { p=$3 } 1' |   

# match the desired patterns and print the subgroup name
awk '/\<PF13304\.1\>/ && /\<PF13401\.1\>/ { print $3 }' RS=
```

Output:

```
x_00004
x_00005
```

Based on the above output you can now extract the relevant lines from `infile`, e.g. add the following to the above pipe:

```
while read sgrp; do
  grep -E "\b(PF13304\.1|PF13401\.1)\b +$sgrp\$" infile
done
```

Output:

```
AAA_21               PF13304.1  x_00004
AAA_22               PF13401.1  x_00004
AAA_21               PF13304.1  x_00005
AAA_22               PF13401.1  x_00005
```

Answer (score 0):

The following `awk` script matches *literal* strings listed one per line in `match_file`, against `data_file`

```
awk 'function endgroup() {
         gmc=0                              # group match count
         for( gi=1; gi<=gz; gi++ ) {        # step through all lines in a group
             split(group[gi],g)             # split one group line 
             for( lix in lms )              # for each literal match string index 
                 if( lix == g[2] )          # does literal match string = group record $2  
                     mrec[++gmc]=group[gi]  # group matched record array, and inc match count
         } 
         if( gmc==lmz ) for( mri=1; mri<=lmz; mri++ ) print mrec[mri]
         delete group; gz=0
     }

     BEGIN{ p3=FS } # an impossible previous value of $3 of "data_file"

     # process "match_file"
     NR==FNR { lms[$0]   # build array with literal match strings as indices
               lmz++     # literal match strings array size 
               next } 
     # process "data_file"
     p3!=$3 && p3!=FS { endgroup() }
     { group[++gz]=$0; p3=$3 }

     END{ if( p3!=FS ) endgroup() }
' match_file data_file
```

Output:

```
AAA_21               PF13304.1  x_00004
AAA_22               PF13401.1  x_00004
AAA_21               PF13304.1  x_00005
AAA_22               PF13401.1  x_00005
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
awk '(/x_00004/ || /x_00005/) && (/PF13401.1/ || /PF13304.1/)' your_file
```

or this, principally the same but with a more readable grouping

```
awk '(/x_00004/ && (/PF13401.1/ || /PF13304.1/)) || (/x_00005/ && (/PF13401.1/ || /PF13304.1/))' your_file
```

---

*Example*

The input file

`cat foo`

```
AAA_21               PF13304.1  x_00004
AAA_22               PF13401.1  x_00004
SMC_N                PF02463.14 x_00004
AAA_29               PF13555.1  x_00004
DUF258               PF03193.11 x_00005
AAA_15               PF13175.1  x_00005
AAA_21               PF13304.1  x_00005
AAA_22               PF13401.1  x_00005
SMC_N                PF02463.14 x_00005
AAA_15               PF13175.1  x_00006
AAA_21               PF13304.1  x_00006
AAA_22               PF13401.1  x_00007
SMC_N                PF02463.14 x_00007
```

The command

`awk '(/x_00004/ || /x_00005/) && (/PF13401.1/ || /PF13304.1/)' foo`

```
AAA_21               PF13304.1  x_00004
AAA_22               PF13401.1  x_00004
AAA_21               PF13304.1  x_00005
AAA_22               PF13401.1  x_00005
```